# Installed gnome control center, now getting heaps of problems

Tags: gnome, software-center, themes

I installed gnome control centre following the instructions from [How to geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/196635/an-official-google-drive-for-linux-is-here-sort-of-maybe-this-is-all-well-ever-get/) because I wanted to use google drive on 16.04. Installation worked, googledrive worked and I was happy. Then I restarted my computer and everything has gone nuts. The desktop changed to black,right-click menus are barely readable and squashed up, the theme colours are replaced with really bad colours, but the worst part? the OK/Cancel buttons etc. don't appear in all applications so I can't even change things back manually... the whole OS is only half useable.

Does anyone know what's gone wrong and how can I fix it? Ideally without needing a fresh install and ideally keeping access to googledrive in some form, though it's not necessary.

Here is screen shot of the appearance window:
[image]

Comment: Which desktop environment were you using before this ? Unity, MATE, XFCE4, LXDE, or KDE ? Or rather : Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu or Kubuntu or something else ? A reinstall might be too hasty, as another DE could possibly fix your problem.

Comment: not sure exactly, but I think it was Unity

Comment: Try a unity-desktop re-install? Or whatever desktop you used previuosly.

Comment: tried to do that and it's even worse now. I can get to the desktop, but it flashes between black desktop with icons and a background image. no side bars or top bars at all

Comment: I've tried following this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears but it doesn't fix it, and the command `sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz/` doesn't do anything